# Firefox - locally modify addon and mandatory singing

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I've been using [fast dial](https://addons.mozilla.org/hu/firefox/addon/fast-dial/) for ages. With my quick and simple random background script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeImg() {
var fullpath = "file:///C:/Users/shdow/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/qwvpaoc7.default/images/";
var newImgNumber =Math.floor(Math.random()*231);
document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + fullpath + "wp" + newImgNumber + ".jpg" +')';}
window.onload=changeImg;
</script>
```

The script is diretcly added to head of the file: chrome://fastdial/skin/icons/fastdial.html Now, lately with horrible mandatory singing, Firefox disables the modified addon as an 'unsigned extension'

I've tried adding my script to greasemonkey, but apperantly it doesn't run on chrome://

So, i have to reinstall the addon, and modify it locally, every time I restart firefox. Very annoying. Is there anything I can do to get back my random backgrounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Add-ons/Extension_Signing#FAQ

> - What are my options if I want to install unsigned extensions in
>     Firefox?
>
>   - The Developer Edition and Nightly versions of Firefox will have a setting to disable signature enforcement. There are also be special
>       unbranded versions of Release and Beta that will have this setting
>       (see , so that add-on developers can work on their add-ons without
>       having to sign every build. To disable signature checks, you will need
>       to set the xpinstall.signatures.required preference to "false".
>       type about:config into the URL bar in Firefox
>       in the Search box type xpinstall.signatures.required
>       double-click the preference, or right-click and selected "Toggle", to set it to false.

Alternatively you can alter the addon's ID, make an AMO account and submit it for signing as unlisted addon which you can use for yourself.

Comment: Thank you, I went with the dev edition. Going to take some time to get used to blue icon.